# How does a JVM execute the Inheritance tree structure?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

```
class Vehicle {
    public int wheels;
    public int lights;
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
    public int wheels =4;
    public int lights =2;

    public void lights_on( int lights) {
        //Code to onlights 
    }
}

class BMWCar extends Car {
     public int wheels = 4;
     public int lights = 4;
}

public class TestCar {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //Creating a new instance of BMWCAR by calling the default
        // constructor provided by the constructor

        bmwCar = new BMWCAR();
        bmwCar.lights_on();
    }
}
```

In the above example, when I run the `TestCar.java` file, The JVM's class loader loads the `TestCar` file into the method area, and it executes the main method. When a `bmwCar` instance is created, it calls the default constructor of the `BMWCar` class and executes the super constructor, which is the `Car` class's default constructor. I would like to know why when the `bmwCar.lights_on();` method is called the JVM looks for the `lights_on` method and in the `bmwCar` object it initalizes the value of instance variables wheels and lights i.e. `4` and `4`.

When the `lights_on();` method is executed in the `Car` class, does the JVM reintialize the value? How is the reference passed from `bmwCar.lights_on` to the `Car` class `lights_on` method? I am looking for a detailed answer about the workflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are declaring member variables `wheels` and `lights` in class `Vehicle`, and then you're declaring member variables with the same name in subclasses `Car` and `BMWCar`.

Note that member variables are **not** overridden like methods; the member variables in your subclasses *hide* the variables in the superclasses.

So, there is not one set of member variables - there are three! You see one of those three depending in which class your method is. The member variables of the superclasses are not somehow reinitialized. Inside the method `lights_on` in class `Car`, you'll see the variables `wheels` and `lights` of class `Car`, with the values 4 and 2.

Using member variables with the same name as in a superclass should be avoided, as it's confusing, and it's not doing what you might think it does.

Comment: @Jesper Thanks for your answer , I would like to know how the JVM behaves when i redeclare the variable in an Inheritance Structure  . How does the JVM identifies the lights_on method  and executes the method which is in the Car class , will the reference of the parent class would be  added by the compiler itself  .can you share some resources if any Thanks

Comment: I think what you want to know is what "polymorphism" is. Have a look at this from Sun's Java Tutorials: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Answer (score 1):

Don't redeclare the member variables put do it like this

```
public class Vehicle {
  public int wheels = -1;
  public int lights = -1;
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
  {
    wheels = 4; //set inherited member variable
    lights = 2; //set inherited member variable
  }

  public void lights_on(int lights){
    System.out.println("Parameter to lights_on: "+lights);
    System.out.println("Wheels: "+wheels);
    System.out.println("Lights: "+this.lights);
  }
}

class BMWCar extends Car {
  {
    wheels = 4;
    lights = 4;
  }
}

public  class  TestCar {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    //Creating a New Instance of BMWCAR by calling the default Constructor provided by the constructor
    Car car = new BMWCar();
    car.lights_on(1);
    car = new Car();
    car.lights_on(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: @jitter Thanks for your answer , I would like to know how the JVM  behaves  when i redeclare the variable , I would like to know will there be any Ambiguity during the compile time itself or  will there be Run time exception  for redeclaring the member variables.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, the JVM refers to and looks up the field by its name, type and class. See the [GETFIELD opcode](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Instructions2.doc5.html) in the JVM spec.

In practice, the JIT compiler (at least in Hotspot) compiles to native code which simply access memory at a given offset of the object's data (i.e. the JIT compiler pre-computes the field offset). (Sorry, I don't have a reference for this, but if you get the debug version of the JVM you can ask it to output its assembler code and see that that's what it does.)